# what is relationship IFrameworkView IFrameworkViewSource and OnPointerPressed

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I am trying to figure out which of the 2 interfaces mentioned is being implemented by OnPointerPressed.

```cpp
struct App : implements<App, IFrameworkViewSource, IFrameworkView>
{
    void OnPointerPressed(IInspectable const &, PointerEventArgs const & args)
    {
    }
}
```

`OnPointerPressed` is part of `Control` class

And I don't see the relationship between `Control`, `App`, `IFrameworkViewSource`, or `IFrameworkView`.

As WinRT UWP uses a lot of interfaces it might help if sample code indicates which interface is being implemented when adding functions.
Would seriously help the learning curve, if that's the point of the samples. Else you'll have to be digging through interfaces to understand the sample code.

Comment: `OnPointerPressed` isn't an interface member. It's just a regular member function of your `App` type, that (presumably) will be used as an event handler for the [UIElement.PointerPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed) event. Event and delegate can be connected through code or XAML.

Comment: Thanks for the update , i forgot to mention i was consuming  winrt c++ event in uwp c# and via that route i had to use  Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPressed += OnPointerPressed; I assume in winrt PointerPressed is in UiElement. Thanks again

Comment: So, your issue is solved?

Comment: Yes thanks Inspectables comment led me to CoreWindow.PointerPressed  where i was able to install handler.

Comment: If you have solved your issue please feel free post your answer below and accept it .